# Android app launch source

Tags: android

I would like to know the source from which my app launch has happened like home screen or browser or Ok google. If browser what was the referer url without UTM.

Is there a way to track. If so please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the solution.

`intent.getExtras()` and `activity.getReferrer()` gives all the data you want.

Comment: For completeness, from the docs: `Note that this is not a security feature -- you can not trust the referrer information, applications can spoof it.`

Answer (score 0):

You can set several separate different `intent-filter`'s in Your app for launch from browser, for launch from home screen, etc. and analyze it's intent data or `action`. Something like that:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();

if (action.equals("com.yourapp.intent.action.startfrombrowser")) { 
  ...
} else if (action.equals("com.yourapp.intent.action.startfromhomescreen")) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi , basically I'm looking for something equivalent in android to http document.referer header as of in web .