# How to know if your app was enabled by Hey Siri or OK Google?

Tags: android, ios, sirikit

I want my app to basically know when the user spoke to the device and switched to my app (or launched it). Something like:

“Hey Siri, ”

Or

“OK Google, ”

That’s it. From there, my app would automatically emit a prompting sound and enable the microphone for eg more complex commands, which I plan to use OpenEars or other onboard AI for — no need to send to server.

But how do I know on iOS and Android that the app was put into the foreground by Siri or Google Assistant?

Comment: On iOS, you don't if the user just used the generic "open myApp" command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278969/android-app-launch-source

Comment: Is that answer for both ios and android?

Comment: Also: [Determining whether iOS application was launched via Siri](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19149587/295004)

Comment: On iOS, you can add SiriKit to the app and only if the user says "Hey Siri, Open SomeApp" it will open. Otherwise it doesn't need to open and the extension is ran. If your app is being interacted with by SiriKit, your will get a delegate called within your SiriKit extension so you know whether or not the user is talking to your app vs. another app.. The delegate (in the intent) call doesn't mean your app was opened, but it does mean the user is asking for suggestions or answers from your app..

Comment: @Brandon could you please add some reference to what you say? I didn't find anything like this on the internet and I'm really interested